# How to remove sum and difference terms while computing frequency from fft?

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, frequency-spectrum, digital-communications

I am currently operating in vhf band AND trying to detect frequencies using Fast Fourier transform thresholding method. While detection of multiple frequencies , i received spurs(May not appropriate word) in addition with original frequencies, Such as in case of f1,f2 that are incoming frequencies i also receive their sum f1+f2 and difference f1-f2.

i am trying to eliminate these using thresholding method but i can't differentiate them with real real frequency magnitudes. Please suggest me some method, or methodology to eliminate this problem

Input frequencies F1, F2 Expected frequencies F1,F2 Receive frequencies ,F1,F2,F1-F2,F1+F2

Comment: Sounds like you are experiencing [intermodulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermodulation), which are usually due to nonlinearities of your system. No easy way to avoid them, what you are going to need to estimate their severity is calibration to estimate a nonlinear model of your system, e.g., coefficients of a polynomial (NB: they might be frequency-dependent).

Comment: try a lower gain